# how can i make a Markup Language in XML?

Tags: xml

i am wondering how i could make a markup language in XML, as well as the file structure and what code goes in the files and if i get a file ending like .mml or .thisml?

thanks, Lordtenteth

Comment: It is very vague what you want exactly. Xml IS a markup language.  Look here http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ how to make a xml file and what markup to use.

Comment: Yes but i heard you can make it into a ML like sportML is a ML

Comment: SportML is an exchange standard for international press based on xml. This is how people exchange data. They have data which needs to be exchanged, they thought of a format how to send it in xml and they created a standard for this. My point is, I still don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish something for my CMS to have its own secure ML as well as use it on my websites i make.

Comment: I think you mean you want to create some sort of API? You simply don't make your own markup language like xml, xhtml or html. You think of what you want to convey as data just like a webpage. Only in stead of using html you use xml.

Comment: hmm, i don't actually know any more... you confused me abit.

Comment: For starters, why do you want the xml? what is its purpose?  Do you need to communicate with mobile applications? RSS newsreaders? Why do you need an xml? What is gonna read your xml? You create a webpage with data for your users to see. But who is gonna receive and read your XML? And what do you want to send?

Comment: i gave up now, but i will revisit this later, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

> i am wondering how i could make a markup language in XML

1. Decide what elements and attributes you want.
2. Document them

Consider writing a schema or DTD.

> as well as the file structure

You decide (within the limits of the XML format).

> and what code goes in the files

XML

> and if i get a file ending like .mml or .thisml?

File extensions are largely meaningless except in so far as you want to use them to associate a file type with an application. Use `.xml` if you want the files to be associated with whatever application the user uses for XML in general. Make up your own if you are writing an application to handle them.

Comment: Well, this helps a little, i have written down what tags and elements i want, but where everything goes is where i am puzzled and how to write it out.

Comment: The [atom spec](http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/) could serve as an example